# How to get started with shell scripting?

Tags: shell, script

My job profile requires a certain level of shell scripting and I have no idea on how would i get started with it 
Please suggest me with the easy ways to getting started with shell scripting.

Thank You
Rj

Comment: Try this: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec01.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of resources on-line. For example:

- [Unix Shell Scripting Tutorial](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/docs/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/unixscripting/unixscripting.html)
- [Linux Shell Scripting Tutorial - A Beginner's handbook](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)
- [The Beginner’s Guide to Shell Scripting: The Basics](http://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/)